# Extraction of endpoint and device extraction from Splunk events

Tags: regex, search, report, splunk

I have an event in Splunk like this:

> [26/Oct/2017:15:03:59 -0500] "GET /service/public/stylesheets/snapshot/fonts/univers/condensedMedium/6a32ccf6-4d13-44ac-b61a-c6b489ba430c.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 57439 "https://smartphone.mycompany.com/service/public/stylesheets/snapshot/fonts.css" "MyCompany for Android/4.1.1 (Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G935P Build/NRD90M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/61.0.3163.98 Mobile Safari/537.36)"

I am trying to use a regular expression to extract endpoint info (service APIs), OS name and its version. I need this to get statistics on different OS (devices) making calls to different APIs of my service.

Something like this while searching Splunk:

```
/service/ service_name="myservice" rex "...." | stats count by <apiname>
```

From examples I found in the Splunk docs, I see that only named fields (in events) can go in regular expressions, as mentioned [in this answer](https://answers.splunk.com/answers/169213/create-two-fields-using-rex-command.html).

In my case, I do not have fields created from the event I am trying to capture.

Comment: What's the exact expected output based on the input provided? Also, it would help verify whether or not the regex is correct if you could provide multiple inputs (maybe different browsers, devices, etc.)

Comment: @ctwheels The output should be table listing/summarizing different API's usage in my service.Afer that I want to be able to see the different OS making those API calls. Its a research to  get an idea of  API usage  in existing framework and type of devices using them.

Comment: Can you provide examples of such input/outputs in the proper formatting? Regular expressions are very sensitive and specific. Give us an exact expected output as you would expect, and provide us with multiple inputs so that we can ensure it works for **statistics on different OS (devices) making calls to different APIs of my service** (update your question to provide this information). We cannot effectively help you if we don't have **all the information**. You've given a subset, which is fantastic, but if you need a regex to work across multiple **different** inputs, provide us them.

Comment: @ctwheels   I don't have a regex in place, I found a workaround the  complicated regex in spunk web by extracting field  .I was able to get this(snapshot) by making use of extracted field(creating new one) on event and then querying on it. But this lot of noise as you can see its different users making same API calls, I want to able to normalize it. The snapshot is what I want to achieve eventually in form of statistics.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue on a previous Splunk project. My advice is to use an app like the one below or use a lookup table. DO NOT try and create a regex that will extract all types of operating systems. This will be a daunting task and requires upkeep.

https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1843/